# Linux shared libraries to find disk information like LUN Id, Storage array information, also to do HBA and mount/un-mount operations

Tags: c++, linux, shared-libraries, redhat, opensuse

Can anyone tell me **shared libraries** on **SuSE and RedHat Linux** which contain:

1. APIs to find out **Disk Information** like ***Disk attributes***, ***LUN Id***, ***VG (Volume group) Id*** and ***Storage array information.***
2. APIs to do [***HBA***](http://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/Host+Bus+Adapter) related operations (like *discovering [WWN](http://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/World+Wide+Name)* numbers on the machine).

I am making a library in C++ which is used to do LUN discovery, LUN attach and detach operation on SuSE and RedHat systems.

I already made this library for IBM AIX platform. But I don't know which shared libraries are used on SuSE and RedHat for doing above operations.

Please also tell me where I can get these Shared Libraries.

Comment: And `mount(2)` and `unmount(2)` are **system calls** (so the `libc` provide C functions for them).

Comment: Under Linux, many of these operations will actually be filesystem operations under `/sys` (in particular, for discovering LUN ids or the WWN of local HBAs or attached devices).  The volume group containing a logical volume can be reliably determined directly from the device path (given `/dev/vg_foo/lv_bar`, you know the VG is `vg_foo`).